# I have a valid Facebook access_token with email permission granted, but still no email info in user's graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, user-permissions

I'm using Facebook's PHP SDK to register the user via Facebook in my website and sometimes I notice the email info is missing in the user's graph, however, I have a valid access token with email permission.

Here is the URL where I'm sending the users to authenticate:

`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=[FACEBOOK_APP_ID]&redirect_uri=[REDIR_URL]&**scope=email**,publish_stream,publish_actions,user_about_me,user_birthday,user_hometown,user_location,user_website`

If I check `https://graph.facebook.com/[USER_ID]/permissions?access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN]` I can see the following:

```
"data": [{
     "installed": 1,
     "status_update": 1,
     "photo_upload": 1,
     "video_upload": 1,
     **"email": 1,**
     "create_note": 1,
     "share_item": 1,
     "publish_stream": 1,
     "publish_actions": 1,
     "user_birthday": 1,
     "user_hometown": 1,
     "user_location": 1,
     "user_website": 1,
     "user_about_me": 1
}]
```

Checking the user's details on `https://graph.facebook.com/[USER_ID]/?access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN]` shows up everything, but the email field is missing.

Where can be the problem? Please let me know if there are some details that can be useful in order to investigate this.

Thank you for your suggestions in advance.

Comment: Did you try `https://graph.facebook.com/me/?access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN]`?

Comment: Yan, yes, the same thing happens. Email is missing.

Answer (score 1):

That's a strange one. Normally, the email address is always returned of the `email` permission is granted - even if privacy settings hide the email address to everyone else.

It could be that the email address that was originally granted to your application has been removed / updated. However, I tested this myself and the updated email address still comes through via the API.

There is a [bug](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/365297990174802) filed with Facebook regarding this. Subscribe to the bug and hopefully it gets resolved soon.

Comment: Thank you! I will check the bug report.

Comment: +1 definitely a bug. Maybe these are users that somehow don't have a confirmed email address with Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

When user gives permission he/she can select not the share email info with your application. You must check it if he/she didn't give the permission you must redirect user to the permission link again until getting mail address.

Comment: Hi Xenon! Thanks for the answer. As you can see, if I check /permissions, the email permission is granted.

Comment: Zsolt when i check my apps for details, i saw some users mail addresses are missing too. But i didn't do what i write above so i think to my self it happened from that reason. Sorry i didn't know the answer